# Passing variable from parent paragraph to children without using getParentEntity

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I have a paragraph called Boxes which is a parent paragraph referencing to many paragraphs of type Box.
I have written the preprocess function of paragraph Boxes which contains some logic that can't be done elsewhere. The result of that code is stocked in a variable called custom_color_weight.

I wanna access this variable in the box paragraph template but I can't move the code that yielded that variable's value outside the preprocess boxes function.

I was searching for a way to pass the variable from preprocess boxes to the preprocess box and hence to the template of the box paragraph Is there any way to do it?

Ps : I can't use getParentEntity in the preprocess Box function to get each time the parent Boxes entity and calculate the value of custom_color right there because that way I will be loading the parent paragarph entity multiple times as I have multiple nested paragraphs of type Box inside the paragraph Boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getParentEntity() is not the problem, it always returns a reference to the same instance. There you could use a bundle class to calculate and store the value. See this change record:

https://www.drupal.org/node/3191609

Then you can replace both preprocess hooks by calling the bundle class method directly from the child Twig template

```
{{ paragraph.getparententity.getcustomcolor }}
```

where getCustomColor() is a method of the parent bundle class.

Comment: But if i use getParententity it doesn't load the parent paragraph again and again ? I didn't understand how it just returns a reference :) Thankk you

Comment: In drupal 9 and 10 getParentEntity loads the parent entity before returning it

Comment: Entity objects are cached in memory and loading the entity again returns the cached instance. This is based on PHP passing objects always by reference.